# How to ensure that legend does not overlap the label on the right Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, axis, axes

please give me a hand about the following code

I  want to ensure:

1. the axes keep square
2. the legend display on the right of the axes and must be outside of the axes.
3. the legend couldn't overlap the y-axis labels
4. must use function 'add_subplot' to create the subplot, couldn't use other functions(e.g twinx...)

I guess we need to calculate the border of y-axis labels , but I don't know how to do.
or is there any other way to make it automaticlly?

the following is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)   
x2 = x1*10 
y1 = x1*2
y2 = x1*10000

def adjust_subplot_layout(fig):
    for ax in fig.axes:
        x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
        y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
        ax.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

def squarify(fig):
    adjust_subplot_layout(fig)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))

loc_val = "upper right"
bbox_anchor = (1.15,1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,frameon=False,sharex=ax1)
lg1 = ax1.plot(x1,y1,label='ax1')
lg2 = ax2.plot(x2,y2,label='ax2',color='tab:red')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right') 
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
lga = lg1 + lg2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lga]
ax1.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor)
ax1.set_ylabel("ax1-ylabel")
ax2.set_ylabel("ax2-ylabel")
ax2.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")


ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2,frameon=False,sharex=ax3)
lg3 = ax3.plot(x1,y1,label='ax3')
lg4 = ax4.plot(x2,y2,label='ax4',color='tab:red')
ax4.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right') 
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
lgb = lg3 + lg4
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgb]
ax3.legend(lgb, labs, loc=loc_val,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor )
ax3.set_ylabel("ax3-ylabel")
ax4.set_ylabel("ax4-ylabel")
ax4.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3,frameon=False,sharex=ax5)
lg5 = ax5.plot(x1,y1,label='ax5')
lg6 = ax6.plot(x2,y2,label='ax6',color='tab:red')
ax6.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right') 
ax5.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax5.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax6.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax6.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")
lgc = lg5 + lg6
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgc]
ax5.legend(lgc, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor )
ax5.set_ylabel("ax5-ylabel")
ax6.set_ylabel("ax6-ylabel")

adjust_subplot_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

code 2

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import mpl


x1 = np.arange(10)   
x2 = x1*10 
y1 = x1*2
y2 = x1*10000

def adjust_subplot_layout(fig):
    for ax in fig.axes:
        x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
        y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
        ax.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

def squarify(fig):
    adjust_subplot_layout(fig)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))

display_mode = 1 # 1 show the legend right
value = mpl.rcParams['figure.subplot.right']
print(value)
x = 1.6
if display_mode == 1:
    loc_val = "upper right"
    bbox_anchor = (value +x ,1.0)
else:
    loc_val = "lower left"
    bbox_anchor = (0., 1.02, 1., .102)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,frameon=False,sharex=ax1)
lg1 = ax1.plot(x1,y1,label='ax1')
lg2 = ax2.plot(x2,y2,label='ax2',color='tab:red')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
lga = lg1 + lg2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lga]

if display_mode == 1:
    ax1.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor)
else:
    ax1.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor, ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)
ax1.set_ylabel("ax1-ylabel")
ax2.set_ylabel("ax2-ylabel")
ax2.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")


ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2,frameon=False,sharex=ax3)
lg3 = ax3.plot(x1,y1,label='ax3')
lg4 = ax4.plot(x2,y2,label='ax4',color='tab:red')
ax4.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right')
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
lgb = lg3 + lg4
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgb]

if display_mode == 1:
    ax3.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor)
else:
    ax3.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor, ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)

ax3.set_ylabel("ax3-ylabel")
ax4.set_ylabel("ax4-ylabel")
ax4.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3,frameon=False,sharex=ax5)
lg5 = ax5.plot(x1,y1,label='ax5')
lg6 = ax6.plot(x2,y2,label='ax6',color='tab:red')
ax6.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right')
ax5.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax5.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax6.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax6.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")
lgc = lg5 + lg6
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgc]
if display_mode == 1:
    ax5.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor)
else:
    ax5.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=bbox_anchor, ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)
ax5.set_ylabel("ax5-ylabel")
ax6.set_ylabel("ax6-ylabel")


fig.set_tight_layout(True)
adjust_subplot_layout(fig)
#fig.canvas.mpl_connect("draw_event", lambda evt: squarify(fig))
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: As for your second request, I wonder if it is possible to change it to `bbox_anchor = (1,1)`.

Comment: Thanks ,  I am not clear my requirment, the legend must be outside of the axes. I will add it to the questions

Comment: `loc_val = "upper left" bbox_anchor = (1.5, 1.0)`Look at it as modified like this.

Comment: thanks, use large x0 of  bbox_anchor is a way , but  it is not good,  as you know, sometimes 1.1 is enough, sometimes maybe we need set it as 2.0.  I guess there is a way to calculate the  value , but I don't know how to do

Comment: `mpl.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = 0.9` You can change the default value in the following way, so you can fix it with the value + X.

Comment: thanks a lot, bug I am sorry about I am a newer ,  I don't understand "value + X" , could you give me a temp code for this ?

Comment: Get the default value, set the value of X (required margin), and set the legend.
`value = mpl.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] x=0.6 .... bbox_anchor=(value+x,1.0)`

Comment: I try you code , it seems not work.  maybe I don't understand what your means,  I modified the question, and add "code 2" part  for your suggestions, could you please help me with the code?

Comment: If you set 'figsize' in code 2 to 'figsize=(16,4)' which is the same as code 1, you can see the axis memory without any problem. Also, I ran code 2 and saw it and noticed it. Since it is affected by the size of the overall graph, you may not be able to find the optimal legend position even if you get the size of the individual graphs.

Comment: And.' You should change your approach to creating multiple graphs before drawing multiple graphs with 'add_subplots' as intended with a single graph.